# Tallying dice rolls - array is printing wrong

Tags: java, arrays

Basically, two dice are rolled randomly a bunch of times and then the two dice values are added together (You roll a 6 and a 3, your total is 9).
The frequency of how many times the total is rolled is stored in totalTally[].
So say you roll 10 times, 3 of those times you roll a total of 9, totalTally[9] = 3.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class dice
{
    public static void main(String a[])
    {

        System.out.println("Creating arrays to store information. This might take a while.");
        int[][] tally = new int[6][6]; //Creates an array called tally to keep track of how many times each number was rolled. [Dice1][Dice2]
        int[] totalTally = new int[12]; //Creates an array called totalTally to keep track of frequency of totals rolled. 
        int[][] roll = new int[36000000][2]; //Creates an array to store dice roll info.
        System.out.println("Rolling two 6-sided dice " + roll.length + " times...");
        Random r = new Random(); //Creates a new random number generator
        for (int i = 0; i < roll.length; i++) //For loop that rolls the dice to fill the length of the array.
        { 
            roll[i][0] = (r.nextInt(6) + 1); //Assigns random number between 1 and 6 to the array for dice 1 result.
            roll[i][1] = (r.nextInt(6) + 1); //Assigns random number between 1 and 6 to the array for dice 2 result.
            tally[roll[i][0]-1][roll[i][1]-1]++; //Increments by 1 the respective result in the tally array.
            totalTally[roll[i][0] + roll[i][1]-2]++; //Increments by 1 the respective result in the totalTally array.
        }
        System.out.println("All done. Results are below.");
        //Following lines print first table header
        System.out.println("\n ROLL SUMMARY:");
        System.out.println("Dice 1 + Dice 2         Frequency");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------");
        for (int i = 1; i <= totalTally.length; i++)//for loop goes through totalTally values
        {
            System.out.println("         " + i + "               " + totalTally[i-1]);
        }
        //Following lines print second table header
        System.out.println("\n DETAILED VIEW:");
        System.out.println("Dice 1      Dice 2      Total       Frequency");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        for (int j = 1; j <= 6; j++) //For  loop goes through dice 1 values
        {
            for (int k = 1; k <= 6; k++) // Nested for loop goes through dice 2 values
            {
                System.out.println(j + "           " + k + "           " + (j+k) + "           " + tally[j-1][k-1]); //Prints line for table with dice values
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the output I am getting for the first table with that code:

```
Dice 1 + Dice 2         Frequency

1                    998639
2                    1997209
3                    2998118
4                    4000336
5                    4999210
6                    6001277
7                    5001144
8                    4000794
9                    3002596
10                    2001501
11                    999176
12                    0
```

Here's my issue: It's not possible to roll a 1 if you are rolling two dice.
And it IS possible to roll a 12.
So all my values need to be shifted.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please read [MCVE] guidance on posting  code. There is no way to know how you generate the array and hence unclear whether `i-1` in `totalTally[i-1]` is a problem or something else.

Comment: How are you generating the random dice rolls?  It is likely that you are using java.util.Random.nextInt(6) which returns numbers from 0..5.

Comment: @StinePike Why? The loop starts at 1

Comment: @StinePike they'll get "array out of bounds" exception with such a strange iteration loop (1 to length instead of regular 0 to <length).

Comment: sorry my bad. Thanks for the correction

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks, I updated to include entire class.

Comment: use \t instead of space

Comment: @Idz I understand that, I am trying to shift the values so they print correctly though

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ -- specifically in your case, use a debugger to look at the array you're printing and see whether it's as you expect. Or (not as good) `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tally))`

Comment: why you subtract 2? that's why the shift is wrong `totalTally[roll[i][0] + roll[i][1]-2]++`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
totalTally[roll[i][0] + roll[i][1]-2]++
```

Why you subtract 2 ?

you should subtract 1 instead

```
totalTally[roll[i][0] + roll[i][1]-1]++
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you "tally" a single die.

```
Random r = new Random();
int[] die1 = new int[5]; //Creates an array to tally die 1    
for (int roll = 0; roll < totalRolls; roll++) {
    die1[r.nextInt(6)] += 1;  // increment the index of the random roll
}
```

Do that for each die.

Your total tally would look like this to count *individual* rolls

```
for (int side = 1; side <= 6; side++) {
    System.out.printf("%d\t%d\n", side, die1[side-1] + die2[side-1]);
}
```

If you want to tally the total of the rolls, sure, start printing at `2`, not `1`

> ```
>     System.out.println("Dice 1 + Dice 2         Frequency");
>     System.out.println("---------------------------------");
>     /// See here 
>     for (int i = 1; i <= totalTally.length; i++)//for loop goes through totalTally values
>     {
>         System.out.println("         " + i + "               " + totalTally[i-1]);
>     }
> ```